# How to send array from Android to PHP Serrver

Tags: php, android

I am having an array with custom objects, which I need to send from Android app to PHP backend.

```
ArrayList<CustomModel> customModels; //Filled with 200+ elements

Gson gson = new Gson();
String str = gson.toJson(customModels);
result = ((new HttpConnection()).sendDataToServer(str));
```

This is the HTTP part:

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);


Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
        .appendQueryParameter("data[]", data);
query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
```

Now this works perfectly find, the server gets the data, but cannot read it. According to the specifications, the server should get Array and not JSON String.

The backend does this with the POST content:

```
$var1 = array_keys($_POST);
```

My question is - how do I send array via POST from Android to PHP?

Comment: I suggest you to use any network libraries like volley and retrofit

Comment: @ChiragSavsani you're right. Retrofit and Volley are best. But for beginners HttpURLConnection is easy hack.

Comment: Yes, Volley is also easy to implement and there is also many documents available.

Answer (score 0):

An example

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
String postData = "A=1&B=2";
writer.write(postData, 0, postData.length());
writer.close();
```

Comment: I do the same - I send JSON String. The backend claims he needs array. I can't imagine sending array from Android to PHP which isn't really a string, as arrays can be anything ...

Comment: Like this `A[0]=1&A[1]=2` or `A[]=1&A[]=2`, PHP will generate an array

Answer (score 0):

**you can receive array on Php side like this.**

```
 $array = $_POST['array'];

    foreach($array as $value) {
       $array_value = $value . "<br>";
    }
```

**You can use below class to send data to Server**

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class BackgroundProcessPOST extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    private String url;
    private JSONObject data;


    //Constructor to initialize variables
    public BackgroundProcessPOST(String url , JSONObject data) {
        this.url = url;
        this.data = data;
    }

    //Doing Background work here
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(this.url); //setting url
            HttpURLConnection connection =
                    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //opening connection to url

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    //setting request method

            OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter
                    (new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            bufferedWriter.write(data.toString());
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream;
            int code = connection.getResponseCode(); // receiving code to check
                                                    // data posted successfully or not
            if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                inputStream = connection.getInputStream(); //if code=200 means data is OK
                                                          // we can receive response
            } else {
                inputStream = connection.getErrorStream();  // data not sent successfully,
            }

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            return builder.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    //This method receives results from background and send them to MainActivity(UI)
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result.contains("Exception")) {
                 //Handle the exception here,,
        } else {
              //Handle  your data here..
        }
    }

}
```

Now you can call **BackgroundProcessPOST.java** from any activity like this:

```
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("timestamp",timestamp);
    data.put("type", "Android");
   String url = "your url here..";

    new BackgroundProcessPOST(url, data, this).execute();
```

Comment: Again - you are sending string with new line between elements. The same as I do but with JSON.

Comment: @ГеоргиАнгелов you can send array the same way.

Comment: @ГеоргиАнгелов i have updated the code.. see if it is working for you now.